# How to fix duration for an incompletely downloaded video?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I am partially downloading a video by specifying the `Ranges` header. I am doing this in python. So, suppose there is video whose duration is 4:43 min and has size 2.56 mb and I am only downloading 1 mb of it, so the actual duration of the video is somewhere around the 2 min mark. Now when I play this video, it plays till it has downloaded but shows 4:43 still as its total duration and abruptly ends like a corrupted video file does. Is there a way I can edit the bytes I receive on downloading the file, so that the video player recognises the exact position after which it should end?

More importantly, I want to know if in videos, the start and end is determined by some set of bytes? Like, if I download a video from the 3000th byte to 6000th byte, it won't play as if its a corrupt video, so I want to know if its possible to add some bytes to the beginning of the file to let the player know that this is the beginning. How does a video player determine the end duration of a video from just the bytes?

Comment: I would suggest looking at the MP4 file structure and more specifically studying what structure defines the beginning of an MP4 file and what ends one.
http://jchblog.u.qiniudn.com/doc/ISO_IEC_14496-14_2003-11-15.pdf

Comment: There's no universal solution. For MP4 videos on the web, the header (the moov box) will be at the front of the file. It will contain duration info. You can remux the downloaded portion using ffmpeg: `ffmpeg -i dl.mp4 -c copy new.mp4`. This won't work if the downloaded portion doesn't include the moov, and the MP4 is not fragmented.